# À quel point est-il acceptable d'utiliser le « r » comme en espagnol au lieu du « r » français?

Tags: prononciation

En français, dans la majorité des accents en France, on utilise le *r* uvulaire [ʀ]/[ʁ], mais dans quelques régions on utilise le *r* alvéolaire [r] comme en espagnol. J'entends beaucoup d'étudiants de français qui prononcent le *r* alvéolaire plutôt que l'autre. À quel point est-ce acceptable ? Ces personnes s'intégreront-elles avec cet accent en France, et seront-elles toujours compréhensibles et intelligibles ?

Answer (score 11):

Même si son utilisation a très fortement décliné, il ne subsiste essentiellement que dans quelques parties du sud-ouest, il n'y aura pas problème de compréhension si un [r] alvéolaire (roulé) est utilisé en français au lieu du [ʁ] apical habituel . C'est aussi vrai quand d'autres variantes de prononciation de la lettre *r* sont utilisées, comme [χ] (accent nord-africain/banlieues), [ɾ] (accent espagnol et corse),  [ɻ] (accent anglais) et [w] (accent antillais).

Answer (score 4):

Comme l'a indiqué jlliagre, l'usage délaisse de plus en plus l'R alvéolaire (aussi nommé *R roulé* ou *apical)*, mais cette prononciation héritée du passé s'est maintenue assez vigoureusement jusqu'à la moitié du XXe siècle dans certaines régions de la France ou d'ailleurs dans la Francophonie (dont Montréal) et continue jusqu'à ce jour d'exister. Elle ne cause d'ailleurs aucune ambiguïté de sens : il existe toute une gamme de sons que l'interlocuteur français analysera spontanément comme une représentation du phonème R, et l'R roulé en est un, se doit même d'en être un au vu de son importance historique.

Molière en son *Bourgeois gentilhomme* nous montre clairement que son usage était habituel en son époque :

> MAÎTRE DE PHILOSOPHIE.— Et l'R, en portant le bout de la langue jusqu'au haut du palais ; de sorte qu'estant frolée par l'air qui sort avec  force, elle lui cède, & revient toujours au mesme endroit, faisant une maniere de tremblement, R r a. *[Le Bourgeois gentilhomme, Acte II, Scène IV]*

Difficile d'arguer contre celui qui par l'excellence de sa langue a pu inspirer l'expression *« la langue de Molière »* pour désigner la langue française.

Notons que cet exemple bien connu des francophones d'aujourd'hui était inspiré de très près par les travaux de Géraud de Cordemoy (1626-1684) présentés dans son *[Discours physique de la parole (1668)](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9612720b/f117.double.r=Discours%20physique%20de%20la%20parole%20cordemoy)*. On trouvera en page 77 de l'édition en référence :

> *[...] & la lettre R. en portant le bout de la langue jusqu’au haut du palais, de maniere qu’étant frôlée par l’air qui sort avec force, elle luy cede , & revient souvent au méme endroit , tandis que l’on veut que cette prononciation dure [...]*

Avant la description du R, Molière décrit les lettres A, E, I, O, U, D et F d'une manière fort adéquate, qui s'approche remarquablement bien de l'usage d'aujourd'hui. Mais R est la dernière lettre présentée et le contexte de la pièce de théâtre est grotesque et vise à déclencher le rire. On aurait pu concevoir un doute quant au sérieux d'une description du R qui s'éloigne autant de la norme. Si doute il y avait, cependant, le sérieux de la publication de Cordemoy suffira à le lever.

---

Merci à Luke pour son travail de détective qui m'a fait découvrir les travaux de Cordemoy.

Comment: True, though you never know with Molière; I wouldn't put it past the playwright to satirize the pompous maître de philosophie further by making his detailed description that of an R which wouldn't even profit M. Jourdain's feigned aristocraticness were he to follow the instructions to a T. ;) That said, [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#To_Modern_French.2C_c._2000) also corroborates uvular R as a phenomenon later than the 18th century.

Comment: His descriptions of the vowels are actually quite accurate, though, aren't they? And so are those of D & F. Nothing revolutionary as far as the way the sounds are produced, even by today's standards.

Comment: On rereading the scene, I see they are. [This version](http://www.toutmoliere.net/acte-2,405364.html) also adds a note at the start of that section: « Molière s’inspire, pour cette leçon de phonétique, d’un ouvrage paru en 1668, le *Discours physique de la parole*, de Cordemoy, un académicien ami de Bossuet et bientôt de La Bruyère. » So your suggestion of taking that scene for an authority is even more on point than I'd have guessed!

Comment: Si donc les ouvrages de référence étaient davantage ma tasse de T, j'eusse pu remonter un peu plus loin dans le passé et citer un savant plutôt qu'un petit comique. Mais j'y aurai au moins gagné la _langue de Molière_. Merci pour la référence, je tenterai de lui faire une place.

Comment: Belle addition.

Answer (score 1):

Comme le mentionnent les autres réponses, the R roulé existe (encore) en français, dans certaines régions – mais le corollaire est qu'il fait partie d'un accent, globalement sudiste, et je pense que prononcer le r "à la méridionale" tout en prononçant le français avec un accent généralement neutre serait un tantisoit bizarre...